# Unable to bind 'this' to callback function of AcquireTokenSilent - Azure AD MSAL & ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am setting up authentication in ReactJS app using AzureAD [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). I am able to obtain id_token and access_token. But while getting access token, I am not able tot refer to local variables via this keyword. I tried to bind 'this' to the call back function but that leads to other issues.

I am implementing all the login functionality as a class.

```
import { UserAgentApplication } from "msal";

export default class AuthService {
  constructor() {
    this.applicationConfig = {
      clientID: "<clientId>",
      authority: "<azureADTenantUrl>"
    };

    this.scopes = [
      "openid",
      "<Other scopes>"
    ];

    this.client = new UserAgentApplication(
      this.applicationConfig.clientID,
      this.applicationConfig.authority,
      this.authCallback,
      {
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/"
      }
    );
  }

  login = () => {
    this.client.loginRedirect(this.scopes);
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.client.logout();
  };

  authCallback = (erroDesc, token, error, tokenType) => {
    if (tokenType == "id_token") {
       this.acquireTokenSilent(this.scopes).then(
         function(accessToken) {
           console.log(accessToken);
         },
         function(error) {
           console.log(error);
         }
       );
    }
  };
}
```

(this is not the actual error message, but a friendly description)

> this.scopes is undefined as 'this' is scoped to UserAgentApplication.

to avoid this, I tried to bind the this to the callback function. I have added the following statement in the constructor.

```
this.authCallback = this.authCallback.bind(this);
```

this leads to another error.

(this is not the actual error message, but a friendly description)

> this.acquireTokenSilent is undefined and 'this' do not have a definition for client to reference using this.client.acquireTokenSilent

So I have hard coded the scopes in the original code and was able to get access token, but again same problem in the call back. This time 'this' is null in the call back.

I tried to move the authCallback to the react component and pass it as a parameter to the service, but that also has same kind of problems.

Any help with how to configure this properly is really appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Why not use `this.client.acquireTokenSilent` instead of `this.acquireTokenSilent` ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the second error message, this.client is always null

Comment: Using popup is not a good way as popup's can be blocked and may interrupt the authentication flow. For your answer you should use redux-persist to keep the state of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this replacement for authCallback.  It doesn't entirely solve the problem, but can get you past the UserAgentApplication's hijacking of "this" object.

```
  authCallback = (erroDesc, token, error, tokenType) => {

    const client = window.client as Msal.UserAgentApplication;

    if (tokenType == "id_token") {
       client.acquireTokenSilent(["openid"]).then(

         function(accessToken) {
           console.log(accessToken);
         },
         function(error) {
           console.log(error);
         }
       );
    }
  };
```

Alternatively, use the loginPopup function instead of loginRedirect as it does not have "this" problem that still exists in current MSAL v0.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working in msal 1.1.1. Try this way:

```
     this.msalClient = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config);
     this.msalClient.handleRedirectCallback(authCallback.bind(this));

     function authCallback(error,response)
     {
       if (response.tokenType === 'access_token' && response.accessToken)
         {
          this.accesstoken = response.accessToken;
         }
     }
```